# Which properties can I test here?

Tags: scala, scalacheck

Given a function like:

```
def f(x: BigDecimal, high: BigDecimal, highest: BigDecimal, thresh: BigDecimal): BigDecimal = {
  val lowMultiplier = BigDecimal(0.2)
  val highMultiplier = BigDecimal(0.4)
  val highestMultiplier = BigDecimal(0.45)
  if (x > thresh)
    if (highest == 0)
      if (high == 0)
        (x - thresh) * lowMultiplier
      else (x - thresh) * highMultiplier
    else (x - thresh) * highestMultiplier
  else BigDecimal(0)
}
```

I was thinking that the following properties make sense for this function but the problem is that properties 2 and 3 are not possible to express.  Maybe this is a strong claim but I can't find a way to do it.
What is the approach to test a function given as such?  Test using an oracle?

property 1: a multiplier is only applied if x > thresh

property 2: once a multiplier is applied no other multiplier is applied

property 3: the priority for the application of multipliers is highest to lowest

Comment: This just seems the wrong approach.  This function presumably had a specification somewhere. You should be testing it meets it. BTW, it would be a lot clearer as `val d= x-thresh; if  (x < = 0) 0 else if (highest != 0) d*highestM else if (high!=0) d*highM else d*lowM` keeping the calculation next to its related test... Or even calculating the multiplier (only) then doing the calc once at the end.

Comment: The function is the specification! I don't understand what do you mean by specification in this context and how it would help me test this function.

Comment: If the function is its own specification, then there is no need to test. It works, by definition. I don't understand in that case why you want to test any properties of it.